# Bike computer that logs all data to smartphone

Tags: bike-computer

Is there a cycling computer that logs all data on your bike and can output that data to a smartphone in a meaningful way?

The issue with something like a Garmin Edge and Strava is the notion of "workouts". Besides times I'm actually working out, I ride my bike everywhere, and though a 1.5km ride to get groceries seems negligible, in a single day I can get 20km of these short rides in.

Ideally, something like a good old Cateye Velo 7, which logs as soon as movement is detected, but can sync all the data to my phone where I can see graphs and all the good things modern health apps provide.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @TyLe. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're asking see [ask] also. You'll see that questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic here, because they have very transitory value. Meanwhile, people will probably chime in using these comments. But I'm confused: you have a solution, so what's wrong with it?

Comment: No solution, that's why I asked. The cateye velo 7 logs data only to the device with no way of exporting. Thanks for your answer though, and I will definitely read up on how to ask!

Comment: Strava works well for this, but you have to start the trip yourself.  Some of the smartwatches (fitbit etc) can synch to strava, but they might not tell the difference between a car ride and a bike ride.

Comment: @Criggie I specifically mentioned Strava as not working for me because I don't want or need to post multiple super short segments and spamming my friends. Strava is good for tracking and recording workouts, not short rides.

Comment: Perhaps google location tracking is all you need.  It runs 24/7 and logs one point a minute.  Basically it shows you where you've been in a day, and has no concept of a trip or speeds or a segment.    
Or you could leave your strava app recording all day and only stop it at night.  Set your strava account as "private" and don't accept followers to avoid spamming them.

Comment: I'm still confused. In what way does an app such as Strava (there are others) not work? Just start it at the start of the day, finish recording at the end. As for not sharing with friends: keep the activities private.

Comment: To make all your activities *private by default*, go to your Strava Settings on Strava.com -> Privacy -> Private Activities. You will see a checkbox to make all activities private.

Comment: Another option if you are worried about too many workouts, simply pause between small journeys and let it go into power save mode. Then when you start up again it simply starts again from where you left off. Not an expert on cycle computers but this is how the garmin running watches work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the [SRM computer](http://www.srm.de/product/powercontrol/) is designed (and priced at close to $800) with the professional athlete in mind. It is said to autostart.

Comment: At least a source would be nice.

Comment: the hyper link is the source....

Answer (score 0):

This was originally going to be a comment as I'm not 100% sure everything comes together to use it like this. I only use GPS - I've bought a (too-) cheap cadence sensor but it's not working yet. With a Bluetooth or ANT+ speed or cadence sensor on your bike, the Android app I use can automatically identify your bike. There's an auto start feature but I haven't tested it - presumably it has to be left running. It's called **IPbike**, and you can try it for free for plenty long enough to get the hang of it (and not expensive if you want to keep it). You can still have strava etc. uploads if you want. And you can get everything out as a GPX file or various other formats. There might be more information online - I've had a few questions about other features and always found an answer. Unlike strava or the other major tracking apps, you keep control of your own data.

The other (expensive) option might be a multisports watch. They can apparently detect what you're doing (for example to switch between triathlon segments). Some phone apps say the same, and you could then look at only the bike segments. But it all comes down to the data export. GPX is a good interchange format, so if you find that a product (app or watch) can export a GPX file per segment, you're probably in luck.